# How to do integration testing for .NET 6 Web Api projects using WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: integration-testing, .net-6.0, aspnetcore-environment

I have been using WebApplicationFactory for integration testing in .NET 5, .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Core 2.1 . It is all working fine for me.

I just create my project with:

```
dotnet new webapi
```

and then I see a web api project **with a Startup class**.

Then I create an instance of the factory class:

```
private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
```

As explained [here](https://blog.markvincze.com/overriding-configuration-in-asp-net-core-integration-tests/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory).

The WebApplicationFactory class is something I really like. It makes it easy to write integration tests. I like it a lot. The Microsoft docs [also refer to it for .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory).

However, how do I, when using .NET 6, make sure my code compiles?

The mentioned command-line statement:

```
dotnet new webapi
```

results in a nicely working project but (when having the .NET 6 SDK installed) without a Startup class...... Now my tests do not compile for just one reason: the Startup class does not exist.

How to fix this? I find it hard to imagine that I cannot write integration tests anymore because `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>` does not compile anymore. But right now, this is the reality I need to deal with. How can I solve the problem? I look forward to being able to use the `WebApplicationFactory` class and continue writing integration tests. But how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Support for this was added in .NET 6 RC1. This is the first version to be supported in production.

You can pass `Program` instead of `Startup`. `Startup` essentially merged into `Program` now. The `Program` class is automagically generated from the top-level statements in the `Program.cs` file. It's not a public class though, so you need to add `InternalsVisibleTo` to the application's project file to make it visible to the test project.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="MinimalApiPlayground.Tests" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In [this example](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/tests/Todo.Dapper.Tests/SmokeTests.cs) Damien Edwards defines a `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` to demonstrate testing a Todo minimal API.

Creating a test app is essentially the same as using `Startup` :
:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetSwaggerUI_Returns_OK()
{
    await using var application = new TodoApplication();

    var client = application.CreateClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/swagger/index.html");

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

class TodoApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Add mock/test services to the builder here
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddScoped(sp =>
            {
                // Replace SQL Lite with test DB
                return new SqliteConnection("Data Source=testtodos.db");
            });
        });

        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

The [Program class](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/src/Todo.Dapper/Program.cs) in that example defines quite a lot of endpoints :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Dapper;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TodoDb") ?? "Data Source=todos.db";
builder.Services.AddScoped(_ => new SqliteConnection(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

await EnsureDb(app.Services, app.Logger);

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}

app.MapGet("/error", () => Results.Problem("An error occurred.", statusCode: 500))
   .ExcludeFromDescription();

app.MapSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!")
   .WithName("Hello");
...
app.MapDelete("/todos/delete-all", async (SqliteConnection db) => Results.Ok(await db.ExecuteAsync("DELETE FROM Todos")))
    .WithName("DeleteAll")
    .Produces<int>(StatusCodes.Status200OK);

app.Run();
```

Comment: In the generated project, there is also no Program class. In your example you use a program class but it is not defined. The Program.cs does not have any class definition like it used to have.

Comment: The `Program` class is automagically generated from the top-level statements in `Program.cs`. I posted the contents of that repo's `Program.cs`. There is no `class Program`, the file's contents are added into a compiler-generated `Program` class

Comment: The reason I ask is that the repository you refer to gives the same problem: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Program' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Todo.Dapper.Tests C:\Github\MinimalApiPlayground\tests\Todo.Dapper.Tests\SmokeTests.cs 44 Active
"

Comment: This is really a "Compiler says no" problem. Startup class and Program class cannot be found according to the compiler. This happens for both the referred repository and my own project.

Comment: @Daan that repository uses .NET 6 RC1 which isn't publicly available yet.

Comment: Is there a proven to work solution for the latest available sdk (preview 7)?

Comment: That's what will be released. Preview 7 doesn't have a `Go Live` license and isn't complete. RC1 will have a `Go Live` license and is already code-complete. There won't be any API changes between it and Release

Comment: @Daan .NET 6 RC1 was released last week so using `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` is working now

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for pointing Damien's project. works perfectly for me.

Comment: For me, it does not work in RC1. "'Program' is inaccessible due to its protection level". The problem is still the same: compiler says no. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @ssilas777 How to you solve the error  "'Program' is inaccessible due to its protection level".

Comment: @Daan did you add `InternalsVisibleTo` ?

Comment: @Daan yes, you need to add InternalsVisibleTo test project. I added that in the assemblyInfo of web solution.

Comment: If I was testing with different Startup classes for different tests, how do I go about this now with the minimal API thing?  Basically I'd need multiple Program files, but this is not possible.  So how to solve this?