# Integration tests api in .net6.0

Tags: api, integration-testing, .net-6.0

SO when I did integration tests for api's, I used tio have a xunit project and used Microsoft.AspNetcore.Mvc.Testing.

There I used a WebApplicationFactory<namespace.Startup>().

According to microsoft docs they provide roughly the same:

```
 // Arrange
    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseStartup<Startup>());
    _client = _server.CreateClient();
```

found here: [api integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/test-aspnet-core-services-web-apps)

However since .net6.0 came out when creating an api project and other projects aswell, they don't seem to have a startup class anymore, all is embedded in the program.cs file, But program.cs file doesn't contain a class either, so i'm a little bit stuck on what to use in my webapplicationfactory<namesapce.startup> -> since there is no startup anymore

Any idea what to do here?

Edit:
program.cs of my api (with controllers)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();



public partial class Program { }
```

my tests:

```
public class ApiTests
    {
        
        private readonly HttpClient client;
        private readonly TestServer _server;

        private const string url = "https://localhost/api/network";

        public ApiTests()
        {
            _server = new TestServer(WebApplicationFactory<Network_Monitor_Agent.Program>);   
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetRequest_Should_Return_Success_Information()
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do integration testing for .NET 6 Web Api projects using WebApplicationFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987057/how-to-do-integration-testing-for-net-6-web-api-projects-using-webapplicationfa)

Comment: ah yes that does answer my question thanks, I'll test later

Comment: this probably answers my question , but i'm stuck in where to place the include. Currently I have placed the itemgroup within the api project and inserted my tests project as name, however I still don't have program in my intellisense

Comment: Would you be able to add more of your code to the question please?

Comment: I have cloned the test project in the other issue, but explained there instead of adding an include reference, He made a public partial class program

Comment: Well doing the same-> adding a opublic partial class program does do the trick I can test atleast.

Comment: I dont understand why Microsoft made this so much more complicated. Instead of quickly making a test server, it now takes a whole day or two to wire one up. Sheesh.