# Override Host configuration in Integration Testing using ASP NET Core 6 Minimal APIs model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, minimal-apis

Being able to customize the Host configuration in integration tests is useful to avoid calling services that shouldn't run at all during testing. This was easily achievable using the standard `Startup` model, overriding the `CreateHostBuilder` from the `WebApplicationFactory`. I tried many many things using the "Minimal APIs" approach and couldn't figure it out.

A full example of what was possible using the `Startup` model, would be something like this:

Program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
            // This is a service that downloads Configuration from the internet, to be used
            // as a source for `IConfiguration`, just like any `appsettings.json`.
            // I don't want this running during testing
            .AddConfigServer();
}
```

As you can imagine, the `AddConfigServer` calls an external web server to download the configuration I want to use in my app startup, but I definitely don't want my integration tests calling this external web server for several reasons: don't want to depend on external services, don't want to hammer my config server with testing requests, don't want my server customizations to be exposed to my tests, etc.

Using the `Startup` model, I could easily change this behavior with this:

```cs
public class MyWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            // No AddConfigServer for my integration tests
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }

    //... other customizations
}
```

However, trying this same approach throws an exception on my integration test startup:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No application configured. Please specify an application via IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup, IWebHostBuilder.Configure, or specifying the startup assembly via StartupAssemblyKey in the web host configuration.
```

Since I don't have a `Startup` class, I couldn't figure out how to properly do this. In fact, since this is common in all my web projects, I abandoned Minimal APIs altogether for the moment, until I figure out how to properly achieve this without a `Startup` class.

PS.: I have all the "partial Program" and "InternalsVisibleTo" in place, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory).

Comment: I think you could refer to this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987057/how-to-do-integration-testing-for-net-6-web-api-projects-using-webapplicationfa

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, I am already using the `WebApplicationFactory` as mentioned in that answer, what I need to do is override the `HostBuilder` altogether. I don't want to replace or add new services to it, I want to start fresh with no services registered in my tests.

Answer (score 13):

In order to make this work, you have to provide your configuration values *twice* both **before** and **after** the minimal API Program.cs runs.

Here's how I did it:

```
public class MyFixture : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configurationValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "MyConfigSetting", "Value" }
        };
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(configurationValues)
            .Build();

        builder
            // This configuration is used during the creation of the application
            // (e.g. BEFORE WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args) is called in Program.cs).
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
            {
                // This overrides configuration settings that were added as part 
                // of building the Host (e.g. calling WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)).
                configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(configurationValues);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is genuinely golden. It's not really well documented and it solves the issue of changing configurations used to dynamically register services at host-building time (`if (host.Configuration.GetValue<bool>(...))`) for tests.